# Difficulty assigning a tensor element (tensor unhashable, can't assign function to call)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

My data is input in a 5x16 matrix with the first four columns being coordinates for the rank 4 2x2x2x2 tensor and the last column being a value for that element. The way I've tried to assign these values has been giving me two errors.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
N = 2

Z = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0.77460594], [1, 1, 1, 2, 0.2444343 ],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 0.2444343 ], [1, 1, 2, 2, 0.49572458],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 0.2444343 ], [1, 2, 1, 2, 0.11234285],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 0.11234285], [1, 2, 2, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 0.2444343 ], [2, 1, 1, 2, 0.11234285],
 [2, 1, 2, 1, 0.11234285], [2, 1, 2, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 2, 1, 1, 0.49572458], [2, 2, 1, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 2, 2, 1, 0.30349089], [2, 2, 2, 2, 1.05571294]],)

T = {tf.zeros(
   [N, N, N, N], dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None
)}


for b in range(N ** 4):
        i = (Z[b][0] - 1)
        j = (Z[b][1] - 1)
        k = (Z[b][2] - 1)
        l = (Z[b][3] - 1)
        def T(i, j, k, l, b):
            T.ref([i][j][k][l]) = Z[b][4]
```

Without the .ref() after the T it gives me the "Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key" error. With it it gives a simple

```
T.ref([i][j][k][l]) = Z[b][4]
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Definitely feels like I'm not assigning values properly, just not sure what I'm able to do.

Comment: I haven't worked with TensorFlow before. Is the function definition in the loop a common idiom? It looks weird to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you want to obtain by defining `T` like so: `T = {tf.zeros([N, N, N, N], dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None)}`?

Comment: @anroesti I doubt it's common on the grounds that it's probably wrong. The idea was that I'd fill in the 5 variables with values given by the for loop and assign a value to that matrix element in T. The .ref() came after the TypeError said it was unhashable and to use that

Comment: @Anwarvic There I was just trying to create an empty tensor that I could then fill via the for loop

Comment: What you are *actually* doing in the second-to-last line is defining a new *function* named *T*. Maybe remove the second-to-last line, and replace the last one with `T[i][j][k][l] = Z[b][4]`?

Comment: Also, why is your initial value (zeros) of T wrapped in braces?

Comment: @anroesti That was what I had initially which gives the same set of errors

Comment: I would definitely remove the function definition and leave it removed. You're not calling it anywhere and it is shadowing the variable T. Do you understand what a function definition does?

Comment: @anroesti I'm not quite sure why I put it in braces, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @anroesti I'm not entirely sure what a function does besides creating a local scope and basic function stuff.

Comment: Okay, I was just trying to feel whether you had a basic understanding of the language. If not it might be better to do a Python tutorial instead of just throwing in random braces and function definitions in the hopes that it will work. But let me know, after removing the function definition and the braces, what is the error mesage now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few minor errors while creating the variable `T` and also during assignment of value in the `for` loop. Have fixed those errors and below is the working code. In the code, have explained the changes as comments.

**Code -**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
N = 2

Z = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0.77460594], [1, 1, 1, 2, 0.2444343 ],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 0.2444343 ], [1, 1, 2, 2, 0.49572458],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 0.2444343 ], [1, 2, 1, 2, 0.11234285],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 0.11234285], [1, 2, 2, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 0.2444343 ], [2, 1, 1, 2, 0.11234285],
 [2, 1, 2, 1, 0.11234285], [2, 1, 2, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 2, 1, 1, 0.49572458], [2, 2, 1, 2, 0.30349089],
 [2, 2, 2, 1, 0.30349089], [2, 2, 2, 2, 1.05571294]],)

# Use (N, N, N, N) instead of [N, N, N, N] for shape
# Make it of tf.Variable so that we can use assign in for loop
T = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(
   (N, N, N, N), dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name=None 
))

# Use assign for assigning the value
for b in range(N ** 4):
        i = tf.dtypes.cast((Z[b][0] - 1), tf.int32)
        j = tf.dtypes.cast((Z[b][1] - 1), tf.int32)
        k = tf.dtypes.cast((Z[b][2] - 1), tf.int32)
        l = tf.dtypes.cast((Z[b][3] - 1), tf.int32)
        T[i,j,k,l].assign(Z[b][4])

print(T)
```

**Output -**

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2, 2, 2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.77460593, 0.2444343 ],
         [0.2444343 , 0.4957246 ]],

        [[0.2444343 , 0.11234285],
         [0.11234285, 0.30349088]]],


       [[[0.2444343 , 0.11234285],
         [0.11234285, 0.30349088]],

        [[0.4957246 , 0.30349088],
         [0.30349088, 1.0557129 ]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @CriminyMorel - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.